# Async load data into controller

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm currently learning AngularJS and similar stuff, and today I've encountered a problem (probably with async).
What I'm trying to do, is to use an Angular factory to get some data from Firebase and then use the data in a controller.

```
App.factory('Jobs', ['$firebaseObject', function($firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/Jobs');
  return $firebaseObject(ref);
}]);

App.controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Jobs', function($scope, Jobs) {
  Jobs.$bindTo($scope, 'allJobs');
  console.log($scope.allJobs);
}]);
```

This is working pretty OK. When I put `{{ allJobs | json }}` in a template- it is updated after few seconds. The problem is that in the controller `$scope.allJobs` is returning undefined (probably because the response from Firebase arrived later than the code has been executed.

My question is, how to write it, so I can access $scope.allJobs directly in the controller?

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do to `$scope.allJobs`. E.g. if you want to display it, the answer is: "don't use console.log, but use {{ allJobs | json }}". But since you already use the latter (+1 upvote for that): what do you want to do with `$scope.allJobs` in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
App.factory('Jobs', ["$firebaseObject",
function($firebaseObject) {
        // create a reference to the Firebase where we will store our data
        return function(url){

           var ref = new Firebase(url);
           // this uses AngularFire to create the synchronized array
           return $firebaseObject(ref);

        };
    }
  ]);
```

Then in your controller:

```
App.controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Jobs', function($scope, Jobs) {
    $scope.allJobs = Jobs('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/Jobs');
    $scope.allJobs.$loaded().then();
}]);
```

This is showing the $loaded method as opposed to $bindTo.  As the other answers/comments mention, $bindTo may be the better way to go.

Comment: Sorry this is to much code for a simple operation, in a moment I will post a solution.

Comment: I did the factory like that so that he can pass it any firebase path making the factory reusable. It may add a line of extra code, but its more practical.  I don't think it deserves a downvote...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `allJobs` is loaded asynchronously, which is the issue.

Comment: You're right, I added $loaded to handle the async issue.  I realize $bindTo may be better, but I've always used $loaded successfully.  Just showing an alternative...

Answer (score 1):

Referencing to this Firebase documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-bindtoscope-varname

I can just do it very very simple:

```
App.controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Jobs', function($scope, Jobs) {
  Jobs.$bindTo($scope, 'allJobs').then(function() {
    // now I have access to $scope.allJobs when everything is downloaded from Firebase
  });
}]);
```

Comment: This is only the correct answer if you want 3-way binding. Otherwise, you should use `$loaded()`.

Comment: @AnidMonsur yes, but I've also read in that docs that $loaded() should be used only for debugging.

Comment: I didn't know that. Where's that stated?

Comment: @AnidMonsur https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html "It's also possible to do this directly in the controller by using the $loaded() method. However, this method should be used with care as it's only called once after initial load. Using it for anything but debugging is usually a poor practice."

Comment: Thanks for that. For what it's worth, `$bindTo()` uses `$loaded()` internally. I believe `$loaded()` is fine to use as long as you understand the promise is only resolved once. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/src/FirebaseObject.js#L146